# Magnetic Field lines within the cylindrical soft iron core within a galvanometer

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I know that magnetic field lines are radial in a galvanometer because of the soft iron core. My question is if they are indeed radial then they should meet at the centre of the cylindrical iron core, but this is not possible as field lines cannot meet, so how will the magnetic field lines be within the soft iron core. [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=galvanometer+field+lines&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj-oY_wivnfAhVSFSsKHdXVDWYQ2-cCegQIABAC&oq=galvanometer+field+lines&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-img.3...824.5338..5470...3.0..0.230.2496.0j13j1......0....1.........0i67j0j0i5i30j0i8i30j0i24j30i10.Ys1A9SxYYp0&ei=1bFCXL7jDdKqrAHVq7ewBg&bih=706&biw=393&client=ms-android-xiaomi&prmd=ibnv#imgrc=HVyyH_TLjYPXCM) is the link for a figure of galvanometer field lines.

Comment: Related question : [Why is the torque exerted by the magnetic field in a moving coil galvanometer independent of the angle of rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/533794/238167)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is how the soft iron](http://macao.communications.museum/eng/exhibition/secondfloor/MoreInfo/2_2_1_MagneticFields.html) interacts with a magnetic field : it becomes a magnetic dipole, south to the north and north to the south of the original field.

[image: magfield]

and [here is a galvanometer](http://www.ncert.nic.in/html/learning_basket/electricity/electricity/effects_of_current/galvanometer.htm) from your search list

[image]

The radial lines within the soft iron cylinder imposed by the geometry: making the face of the magnets radial and thus the soft iron displays radial north and south direction. The "meeting " is geometrical, it means that at the center of the soft iron cylinder the field will be high, but it will be limited in space by the magnetic domain structure, and in strength by the strength of the permanent magnets.

Comment: Can you please answer with the help of a figure as to how will the magnetic field lines be at the centre of the soft iron cylinder? Even a rough sketch will do . The red lines in the figure that I have refer to the coil and not the magnetic field lines within the magnet (just to be clear). Thanks